# Extracting the Silhouettes Coordinates

Tags: java, coordinates, rectangles

[image]

From the image I posted up there, I have all the coordinates from those rectangles in the Figure C saved in an array of the class Figure.

**Figure:**

```
public abstract class Figure {

    private int left, right, height;
    protected Coordinates[] coords;

    public Figure() {

    }

    public Figure(int left, int right, int height, Coordinates[] coords) {

        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.height = height;
        this.coords = coords;
    }

    public int getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public int getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public Coordinates[] getCoords() {
        return coords;
    }

    public abstract void setCoordinates();

    public abstract void showCoordinates();
}
```

**Coordinates:**

```
public class Coordinates {

    private float x, y;

    public Coordinates() {

    }

    public Coordinates(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Thing is, I have to find the coordinates of the silhouette from the whole graph the way it is in Figure D ([see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFR4h.png)) using the coordinates from the array already mentioned.

Example (See the Image Reference):

```
 1st Rectangle Coordinates are: (1,0)(1,11)(5,11)(5,0)
 2nd Rectangle Coordinates are: (2,0)(2,6)(7,6)(7,0)
 3rd Rectangle Coordinates are: (3,0)(3,13)(9,13)(9,0)
 4th Rectangle Coordinates are: (12,0)(12,7)(16,7)(7,0)
 5th Rectangle Coordinates are: (14,0)(14,3)(25,3)(25,0)
 6th Rectangle Coordinates are: (19,0)(19,18)(22,18)(22,0)
 7th Rectangle Coordinates are: (23,0)(23,13)(29,13)(29,0)
 8th Rectangle Coordinates are: (24,0)(24,4)(28,4)(28,0)


 The Coordinates of the Silhouettes from all those rectangles should be:
 (1,11)(3,13)(9,0)(12,7)(16,3)(19,18)(22,3)(23,13)(29,0)
 This is where I'm stuck thinking how I'll get these coordinates.
```

I'm not asking someone to do it for me or something like that, I just want to think from where to start cause all I've tried failed so far, so any tips or ideas would come in handy! thank you so much in advance! Good nite.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to obtain the union of each cluster of overlapping rectangles. Java's `java.awt.geom.Rectangle` class has a `createUnion(Rectangle2D)` method that will 'absorb' a second rectangle into the first (via a 'union'). However, this doesn't solve your clustering problem.

If the the number of rectangles you are trying to process is relatively small and clustering is only needed in one dimension (i.e. horizontally), the most straight-forward way would be to keep a list of rectangles that haven't already been clustered, loop through each unclustered rectangle, remove the first rectangle into its own new 'cluster' and then perform an intersect with all other unclustered rectangles to determine if the pair should be clustered. The `java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.intersects(Rectangle)` method is perfectly suitable for this. If they intersect then the rectangle that intersects should be removed from the list of unclustered rectangles and added to the current cluster.

The `Rectangle2D` class doesn't quite match your storage of coordinates, but a mapping will be reasonably straight forward.

Once you have your sets of clustered rectangles, you still need to find the path of each Polygon that bounds all rectangles in a given cluster. If your sample picture is indicative of all rectangles such that they all have their bottom edge at the same 'height' and none of your rectangles have different rotations, this will be a lot easier.